# Open Local PDF in Application from Webpage (UNC path)

Tags: php, html

I have a web page that creates links to Excel & PDF files that are on a local server. I'm successful with opening Excel files, however not with PDFs. Please consider the code below:

```
$fileLink = sefs1/Standards/Cable Trays.pdf
$fileName = Cable Trays

} else if($fileType == "pdf") {
    echo "<td><a href='file://".$fileLink."'>".$fileName."</a></td>";
}
```

How can I open the PDF in the user's default PDF application?

EDIT: Please see expansion on code below:

```
// Print table
while($queryTableInfo->fetch()){
    $fileType = pathinfo($fileLink, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    echo "<tr>";
        // Format the link depending on file type
        if(!empty($fileLink)) {
            if($fileType == "xls" || $fileType == "xlsx" || $fileType == "xlsm") {
                echo "<td><a href='ms-excel:ofe|u|file:///".$fileLink."'>".$standardNum."</a></td>";
 //STACK OVERFLOW ISSUE BEGIN
            } else if($fileType == "pdf") {
                echo "<td><a href='".$fileLink."'>".$standardNum."</a></td>";
 //STACK OVERFLOW ISSUE END
            } else {
                echo "<td>".$standardNum."</td>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<td>".$standardNum."</td>";
        }
        $filename = 'filename.html';

        //Additional Information
        echo "<td>".$description."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$revNum."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$issueDate."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

$queryTableInfo->close();
```

file:// and file:/// in the href did not work for me

The Excel links work. The PDF links do not. I also want to open it in the user's default PDF application instead of the web browser. Hopefully this is more clear

Comment: Not valid PHP!! `$error = "Basic string literal issues";` <- thats a hint

Comment: @RiggsFolly the variables are pulled from a mysqli query in another area of my code. Are you referring to how I quickly defined them above or is my syntax incorrect in the href?

Comment: @SamiAji  Please note that we can only help fix what we can see.  If this is not your actual code, then it doesn't do much good.

Comment: Its dangerous showing us pseudo code :) SPecially if you dont double check it for sanity :)

Comment: I would try `echo "<td><a href='$fileLink'>$fileName</a></td>";`

Comment: Please see updated post. That didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper href structure for UNC links to PDFs was found to be:

```
echo "<td><a href='file://///".$fileLink."'>".$standardNum."</a></td>"
```

That is file: with five (5) slashes. This solves the issue for Internet Explorer and Edge. However, with Chrome, you must have users install this plugin or similar on their machines:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enable-local-file-links/nikfmfgobenbhmocjaaboihbeocackld?hl=en

On Firefox, I found no efficient solution to make it deployable with a "one-step install" and not sacrificing the design of the site. In my case, this is an intranet, so I have a bit of control over the users machines and can ask IT to bake this plugin into Chrome on their next OS image for new machines.

For existing machines, the Chrome plugin install proves to be simple enough for a user of any experience to follow.